# MonetDBLite Left Join Syntax

Tags: sql, monetdblite

Working in R and trying to add a column to an existing MonetDBLite table by running a left join with a second table using the following code:

```
dbSendQuery(mdb, "UPDATE table1 
   SET table1.variable = table2.variable 
   FROM table1  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.identifier = table2.identifier;")
```

Returns the error:

```
Server says 'syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '=' in: "update table1 
   set table1."
```

Does MonetDB not support the dot delimiter to reference a field within a table? Many thanks for any insights.

Comment: You mean LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Change `set table1.variable` to `set variable`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But no luck with that. Throws the error: "Server says 'syntax error, unexpected FROM, expecting SCOLON in: "update table1 
      set variable = table2.variable
      f"

Answer (score 1):

Came up with a work around that involves creating a third table rather than updating an existing table, then dropping the original table. (Pretty sure there is a more elegant way to do this, but...)

```
dbSendQuery(db, "create table table3 as
select a.*,
b.variable
from table1 as a
left join table2 as b
on 
(a.identifier = b.identifier);")

dbRemoveTable(db, "table2")
```